# Excel - color one cell if one cell in row contains a value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a datasheet with around 50 rows and 100 columns. Not all cells in the rows and columns have a value. I want to see when a row is empty and when it has a value.

Hence, each cell in column A (starting from row 3) should show a green color when there is at least one value in its corresponding row (starting from column E).

For example:

- A27 has no color, hence there is no value in any of the cells of row 27 (starting from column E).
- A38 has a green color, which means that in row 38 there is at least one cell that has a value (starting from column E).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Conditional formatting using COUNTA over the row

Comment: Can we write TRUE or FALSE in row A to indicate the result of the condition and then with conditional formatting color column A using a simple formula?

Comment: As explained in first comment, `=COUNTA(B2:M2)` Select A2 and down,

Comment: You can try the Conditional Fromatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

[image: Table]

[image: Conditional Formatting]

(The actual) Column B is just for your reference, so you don't need to copy that over.  Column C can be hidden if you'd prefer, I would just caution to take measures so that it isn't easily deleted or altered unintentionally (move to different column or tab, lock, etc).

I've saved a copy of the sample table I created [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GnL7HPdxbdFgml8CFfsLUPSmM7QgF45U/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=116925733799097887306&rtpof=true&sd=true), in case you'd prefer to download and edit it yourself instead of recreating it.